# Gas Error on Uniswap Bot

Tags: gas, error, flashbots

I'm new to all this and I'm trying to code a bot.

The bot is picking up new listings on uniswap but when it goes to put through a transaction I'm getting a gas error.

I'm getting..

`(node:7820) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit (error={"reason":"cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit","code":"UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT","error":{"code":3,"response":"{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"id\":6,\"error\":{\"code\":3,\"data\":`

Can anyone shed light on how I set the gas or gas limit?

I've tried lots of different things but it keeps erroring.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: It is likely an error condition is triggered by the function call.

Comment: Hi Ismael. Do you think this is something you can help me solve? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/99201/errors-when-trying-to-purchase-tokens

Comment: Without looking at the code is hard to say if it will work or not. Perhaps a wrong parameter is passed, a bug in the contract, a bug in the bot.