# Errors when trying to purchase tokens

Tags: uniswap

I'm trying to buy tokens and I'm getting an error and failed transaction.
It's taking the gas fee and then failing.
I've attached the contract and the errors from etherscan and error from terminal.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

If someone can guide me in the right direction I'd be very grateful, at this a few days now and hitting brick wall after brick wall - surely it's a simple mistake I'm making and a simple fix.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If this is the EatTheBlocks `bot.js` code, then I think you're missing an `approve()` call, which his code doesn't have.

`swapExactTokensForTokens()` calls `transferFrom()`, which can't be called without a prior approval.

If you look at his equivalent [PancakeSwap bot](https://github.com/jklepatch/eattheblocks/blob/master/screencast/348-pancakeswap-trading-bot/bot.js), the code includes an `approve()`:

```
const init = async () => {
  const tx = await wbnb.approve(
    router.address, 
    'replace by amount covering several trades'
  );
  const receipt = await tx.wait(); 
  console.log('Transaction receipt');
  console.log(receipt);
}
```